# The Kerberos subsystem encountered an error

Tags: windows, vb.net

I've 2 domain controller one a master (windows server 2008) and one secondary (windows server 2000). I've small codes to check whether user is belong to a group.

```
Public Function IsInGroup(ByVal user As String, ByVal group As String) As Boolean

    Using identity As New WindowsIdentity(user)
        Dim principal As New WindowsPrincipal(identity)
        Return principal.IsInRole(group)
    End Using

End Function
```

If Win 2008 was running, the function work fine. But if we turn off master server and secondary is rise as activated domain controller, the above source code was error about

> "A service for user protocol request was made against a domain
>   controller which does not support service for user".

Anyone know about this issue. Could you please give me a solution for resolving?

Comment: I don't know whether the .NET framework knows how to talk to Windows Server 2000.  There's no particular reason for it to be able to, given that Windows 2000 reached end-of-life some time ago.

Comment: Does .Net wrap codes from libraries in windows core?

Comment: You mean error codes?  I would presume so; the error message you give is associated with error code SEC_E_NO_S4U_PROT_SUPPORT, which appears to be a Kerberos issue; see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I just want to know whether user is belong to group in domain? Can you give me the help?

Comment: There are a number of approaches you could take.  Someone might know a way of tricking .NET into working.  Other possibilities include running `net user` or `net group` in a subprocess and parsing the output, using PInvoke to call suitable Win32 API functions such as `NetUserGetGroups`, or writing a C DLL to do the job and calling it from your .NET program.  (Regardless, I do hope you've got a plan in place to get rid of the Windows 2000 server in the near future, as it should have been gone years ago.)